# Irrational number representation in any programming language?

Tags: java, c++, python, ruby, numbers

Does anyone know of an irrational number representation type/object/class/whatever in *any* programming language?

All suggestions welcome.

Simply put, if I have two irrational objects, both representing the square root of five, and I multiply those objects, I want to get back the integer five, not float 4 point lots o' 9s.

Specifically, I need the representation to be able to collect terms, not just resolve every time to an integer/float. For instance, if I want to add the square root of five to one, I don't want it to return some approximation integer/float, I want it to return an object that I can add/multiply with another irrational object, such that I can tell the object to resolve at the latest time possible to minimize the float approximation error.

Thanks much!

Comment: Most programming languages offer a dedicated type for complex numbers. Is that not good enough?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: The class of irrational numbers is not the same class as the class of complex numbers.

Comment: No. Complex numbers and irrational numbers are two different things.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Complex does not imply irrational

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: The term "irrational numbers" describes the set `R \ Q` (i.e. real numbers which are not rational) and has nothing to do with complex numbers. Certainly a type for complex numbers does not help you in calculating `sqrt(5) * sqrt(5)`.

Comment: Any irrational number? I guess you are looking for "radicals". (But I don't have an answer, other than presumably stuff like Mathematica.)

Comment: Ok, you are right. I tend to get mixed up with irrational and imaginary. My bad.

Comment: Can't say specifically, but general rule: if you have a math need, someone has written a library for it.

Comment: Does Mathematica count as a programming language?

Comment: I'm with Tom, you need to limit the domain of discourse, perhaps to radicals plus a means of place-holding for transcendentals without knowing much about them. There's a limit to how smart any system for irrational numbers can be. For one example, nobody knows whether `pi + e` is rational or irrational. Supposing that it is rational, then no such library written before the proof of that was discovered, has much chance of recovering an exact integer result from multiplying it by its denominator...

Comment: ... in practice for that example there's probably a known lower bound on the denominator that means that calculation isn't likely to come up. But there are a *lot* of such expressions that you can generate from a few known transcendental numbers, and conceivably some of those are rational, with manageable denominators, but very difficult to prove that they're rational.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you are looking for is called symbolic mathematics.  You might want to try some computer algebra system like Maxima, Maple or Mathematica.  There are also libraries for this purpose, for example the [SymPy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/) library for Python.

Comment: Ah! You know, 90% of the time, my problem with finding libraries and gems and such is terminology. Once I searched for "symbolic math...", I found all sorts of stuff. Sympy looks *very* nice. Since I'm geared towards Ruby, Maxima is interesting since it's written in Lisp. GiNaC is a contender, there's also Axiom (which looks like a beast, but it has 40 years of use behind it), plus JAS and JACAL. Thank you very much to everyone who weighed in. Much appreciated!

Comment: [Symbolic](http://brainopia.github.com/symbolic/) for Ruby. Bingo! Again, thanks all for the pointers.

Answer (score 7):

You could try [sympy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/) since you appear to be after symbolic computation and are amenable to using Python.

Comment: You can also use something like Jython if you need to use sympy in Java (as your tags would indicate).

Comment: @Riggy The tags don't really indicate that. It's more that OP is agnostic about programming language.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the already mentioned [SymPy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/) would be the most apropriate way to go - as you might do what you need and do not require that your software be written in a specific purpose proprietary language such as of the mathematical products mentioned.

On the other hand, if you don't want to introduce further dependencies, and your irrational cases are limited to multiplications of square roots, in Python it is an easy task:

```
class Irrational(float):
    def __new__(cls, base, radix=1):
        self = float.__new__(cls, base ** (1.0/radix))
        self.base =  base
        self.radix = radix
        return self
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if  isinstance(other, Irrational) and other.radix == self.radix:
            return Irrational(self.base * other.base, self.radix)
        return float.__mul__(self, other)
```

Example:

```
>>> a = Irrational(5,2)
>>> a
2.2360679774997898
>>> a * Irrational(5,2)
5.0
```

You can pursue it further and include ohter operations and corner cases. But for compes expressions, you'd soon realize you'd need to use symbolic math anyway.

Answer (score 3):

To compile some things that others have said, as well as add a few solutions for other languages...

---

## C++

> #### Piranha

[Try bluescarni's Piranha "computer algebra library"](https://github.com/bluescarni/piranha)

```
// Include the standard I/O header.
#include <iostream>

// Include the global Piranha header.
#include <piranha/piranha.hpp>

// Import the names from the Piranha namespace.
using namespace piranha;

int main()
{
    // Piranha initialisation.
    init();
    // Print the rational number 4/3 to screen.
    std::cout << rational{4, 3} << '\n';
}
```

There is also a *Python* wrapper ("Pyranha") available.

> #### SymEngine

[SymEngine](https://github.com/symengine/symengine) is another C++-based symbolic mathematics library, with wrappers for *Python*, *Ruby*, *Julia*, and *Haskell*. SymEngine integrates nicely with SymPy and Sage, both for Python.

---

## Java

> #### SymJa

[Try axkr's Symja Library](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library)

```
>>> sin(30*degree)
1/2

>>> sin(pi/2)
1

>>> a+a+4*b^2+3*b^2
2*a+7*b^2
```

Alternatively, you can use [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) to get [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/fr/index.html) in Java.

---

## Python

> #### SymPy

As others have mentioned, [SymPy is the go-to for symbolic mathematics in Python](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html):

[image]

---

## Ruby

> #### Symbolic

[Brainopia's Symbolic](https://github.com/brainopia/symbolic) is a symbolic mathematics library (with no external dependencies) for Ruby:

```
0 * x           # => 0
2 + x + 1       # => x + 3
-(x-y) + 2*x    # => x + y
(x**2)**3 / x   # => x**5

Symbolic::Math.cos(x**2).diff(x)
# => -2*(sin(x**2))*x
Symbolic::Math.cos(x).taylor(x,0,3)
# => -0.5*x**2+1.0
```

---

**Please feel free to edit or amend this answer with other symbolic mathematics libraries.** As a rule of thumb, I haven't included any "arbitrary precision" mathematics libraries, because this is not the same thing as an *infinite-precision* symbolic mathematics library. I also haven't included stale packages which haven't been updated recently.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental numeric type in Matlab is a matrix of complex floats. Specifically, if you type `x = 1`,  what you really assign to x is a a 1x1 matrix with its [0,0] element equal 1+0i.

Comment: OP is looking for help with irrationals, not complex.

Answer (score 0):

In ruby there's http://flt.rubyforge.org/ which gives you what you want I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I remember MathMorph in Smalltalk has a representation for AlgebraicNumbers (that includes radicals) as the root of a polynomial of single variable with integer coefficients, lying in a certain interval.
You'll find interesting applications of Sturm's theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem 
You'll have to google a bit and dig in old archives though, MathMorph is an old project...