# Memory and irrationality and floating numbers

Tags: c++, c, memory, bit

Some numbers can not be stored in "memory bits" as their binary representation would make them go endlessly.

In binary 11.111011101110... this is not the exact number. I can't remember exactly what it is right now.

But we can think of it "like an irrational number" in our base 10 that goes on infinitely after decimal place.

Some rational numbers face this problem when converted to base 2. 
So how do we...

1) represent them?

2) calculate them with computer programs?

3) perform operations on them?

Edit: 
To remove Confusion and say thanks:

Ok I said in above post --> to view it or think it like a irrational or a number going long and long in decimal place. please read the word "like".

Now i have a number 0.2 this simple number cannot be represented in binary form. so how to perform Operations over it.

Other Questions are still unsolved .

well just to mention for my belief in people here:

Well go for "library" or approximately storage is not an answer for geeks of stackoverflow as their are certain applications where it is important to have the numbers as they are.

Comment: maybe see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407286/irrational-number-representation-in-any-programming-language

Comment: The example which you have given of "11.110110...." is rounded off as per the precision of the system that you are using.

Comment: 11.111011101110... = 59/15, btw, completely rational. Easily represented by the two numbers 59 and 15.

Comment: @ASHISH you seem to be confusing irrational numbers and numbers with an infinite representation in some base, which can be rational

Comment: As for finding closest reasonable rational approximations to floating point numbers, I think the best results come from continued fractions, cut off at the first “large” jump in the coefficients.

Comment: Christopher: thanks for calculating that but how should i store 59/16 in memory precisely. how many bits required for that?

Comment: They're not irrational numbers, they are periodic numbers. 1/3 is a periodic number in decimal. 1/10 is a periodic number in binary. Both are rational (independent of the base).

Comment: @ASHISH NEGI: The number is 59/15, not 59/16. One way to represent this number is as the fraction 59/15. No precision loss whatsoever. Another scheme is the IEEE floating point format. One huge advantage of this form is that the math coprocessor on your computer understands it, making math operations are orders of magnitude faster. A disadvantage is the limited precision (~ 15 decimal places).

Comment: @ASHISH: You could just use two `uint8_t` and get away with 16 bits, although I'd guess you'd rather user slightly larger numbers for numerator and denominator, for other values. What is your goal? (And please, get the terms right. There is nothing irrational about 1/3 or 59/15.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All integer numbers are represented precisely.
You are talking about fractional and irrational numbers, right?

Irrational numbers cant be represented by binary digits as like by decimal ones. So they can be represented only with specific precision.
The problem with fractional numbers is that not every decimal number can be precisely represented as binary. for example 0.9. That is because of floating point number nature.

The easiest way to solve this problem is to use fixed point numbers - it is basic integer numbers with some numbers fixed to represent fractional part. This method usualy used in financial software/ Where every dollar is represented by 100 cents ) This method have one drawback - it can represent only limited precision of numbers.

Another solution is like for decimal periodic numbers. Represent them as two numbers dividend and divisor. so decimal periodic 0.(3) can be represented precisely as 1 and 3.

Comment: Fixed-point doesn't really solve the problem.  For example, 1.0/3.0 can't be represented exactly in either decimal or binary, either floating-point or fixed-point.  Of course, as you point out, it can be represented exactly as a rational number, storing the numerator and denominator as integers.

Comment: Actually, fixed point doesn't help at all. Both fixed and floating pointer number are of the form m*2^e. The only difference is that floating point numbers store the exponent (e) along with the value, and fixed point doesn't (forcing the code or programmer to keep track of it).

Comment: Ah, I think you meant decimal fixed point, not binary fixed point, but that doesn't change anything. The problem the OP is talking is limited precision, and like you said, that applies to fixed point too. Even more so.

Comment: What's so special about *decimal* periodic numbers? Your suggestion works well for all rationals.

Answer (score 5):

You should look into the floating point numbers standard, and also read ["Everthing every programmer should know about floating point numbers"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

There is specific issues regarding rounding of floating point numbers and their precision when dealing with them, as like you say, we cannot infinitely represent them in our current machines, so these things have been solved to create the best precision possible, however there is certain caveats one has to keep in mind when dealing with them.

Answer (score 1):

They're not irrational numbers, they are periodic numbers. 1/3 is a periodic number in decimal. 1/10 is a periodic number in binary. Both are rational (independent of the base). In fact, whether a number is rational or not never has anything to do with the base.

All rational numbers can be represented as a fraction where the numerator and the denominator are integers. Yes, including all periodic ones. Some system use fractions internally to provide more accuracy. I believe this is what Perl6 will be using instead of floating point numbers.

You can end up with very large numbers internally, and you will still have precision loss when dealing with irrational numbers. For example, you could only approximate pi, perhaps using

```
 314159265358979/100000000000000
```

or

```
3141592653589793/1000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't. We use their approximate values. There are algorithms that can compute them with any precision needed.

And by the way, not every number that is infinitely long is irrational. For example, the number 1/3 is infinitely long in base 10: 0.333333333... and in base 2: 0.0101010101..., but it is rational.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way.
For eaxmple, the number:

```
sqrt(2) * sqrt(2)
```

can be found with symbolic or numeric approaches.

Regarding rationals: one can represent them as a pair of (big) integers and perform arithmetic operations on them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to represent rational numbers you can do it in the same way that you do it on paper, store two numbers, the numerator and the denominator (of course you are best off finding a library to do this for you as there are a lot of nuances to get right).

The rationals that do not have finite base 2 representations are the rationals which do not have powers of 2 in the denominator, 2 being the only prime factor of the base. Likewise for other bases you need to look at the prime factors of the base, so for base 10, the product of powers of 2 and powers of 5 have finite representations.

Irrational numbers are different beasts all together and I don't think relevant to your question, the general technique here is either to approximate them to some finite precision e.g. M_PI or to represent them symbolically and either never calculate them or calculate them at the end to a finite precision.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers with a finite decimal representation that do not have one in binary are repeating rather than irrational. How you deal with them depends on what your needs are. If you are dealing with money you usually use a binary coded decimal or a scaled representation, which guarantee that additions and subtractions are exact up to a certain number of decimal places. In other fields you might use a symbolic representation so as to delay performing actual computations until needed. If you think about it `sqrt(2)` is a finite, exact representation as long as you do not actually evaluate it.