# BigDecimal Rounding

Tags: java, bigdecimal

So BigDecimal can't seem to store numbers that continue infinitely like the answer to 1/3. When I tried that, I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
```

So I decided to use [`RoundingMode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html). When I do `(1/3)*3`, I want it to come back as 1 and not like 0.9 or 0.99 or 0.999 or any form like that. However, if I was to do (1/3)*2, I don't want it to round up to 1.

Answer (score 1):

If your divisor is always 3 you can do your math with integers scaled up by 3 to get exact results, e.g. use 2 to represent 2/3 and use 1 for 1/3. Adding them will get you 3, which stands for 3/3 = 1.

If you need various divisors but still only work with numbers that can be represented by fractions, you might want to look at this question: [Best way to represent a fraction in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474535/best-way-to-represent-a-fraction-in-java)

If you need to exactly represent (and calculate with) irrational numbers, too (e.g. Pi or sqrt(2)), you are probably out of luck. See here: [Irrational number representation in any programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407286/irrational-number-representation-in-any-programming-language)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need rounding for 1 decimal place, try this:

```
BigDecimal base = new BigDecimal("1.0");
BigDecimal result = base.divide(new BigDecimal("3"), 1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

and also read docu [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: That is what I did. I am trying to figure out how to get it back to one if I was to multiply the results by 3.

Comment: not possible. when you do math you need to decide if you need precise result (without rounding) or rounded results (and you lose precision).

Answer (score 0):

If you round your number, you will lose information. With BigDecimal, you will never get 1 with (1/3)*3 unless you round the final result again.

Comment: Is there an alternative to BigDecimal that will allow me to get 1 when I do (1/3)*3 and get 0.6667 when I do (1/3)*2?

Comment: The best alternative is Medo42's answer I think.